# How to map an enum? in proto file, .NET Core 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, enums, grpc

I have this model class:

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Ucdp.Common.Enums.Vendor;

namespace Ucdp.Common.Industry
{
    public class VendorBasicDetailsByChannelModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public VendorMode VendorMode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in that model one field(`VendorMode`) have enum model(`VendorMode`).

enum model has 4 enum types

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Ucdp.Common.Enums.Vendor
{
    public enum VendorMode
    {
        Shopping = 1,
        Discovery = 2,
        ShoppingAndDiscovery = 3
    }

   
}


and this is vendor.proto file

syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "IndustryAPI.Protos";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message ListOfStrings {
    repeated string strings = 1;
}

enum VendorMode {
  VendorMode_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  Shopping = 1;
  Discovery = 2;
  ShoppingAndDiscovery = 3;
}

message VendorModel {
    string Id = 1;
    string Name = 2;
    VendorMode VendorMode = 3;
}

service VendorService {
    rpc GetVendorBasicDetails(GetVendorBasicDetailsRequest) returns (GetVendorBasicDetailsResponse);
}

// requests
message GetVendorBasicDetailsRequest {
    string channelId = 1;
    string VendorCreatedDateStart = 2;
    string VendorCreatedDateEnd = 3;
}

message GetVendorBasicDetailsResponse {
    repeated VendorModel Vendor = 1;
}

I want to map each field with message
var Vendor = new VendorModel
                    {
                        Id = vendor.Id.ToString(),
                        Name = vendor.Name,
                        VendorMode = vendor.VendorMode
                    };
```

how to map an enum?

Answer (score 0):

You first install the **nuget package** [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/)

Then install its dependency [AutoMapper Dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/)

```
Using AutoMapper;

namespace sample.auto
{

    public class Mapper : Profile
    {
        public Mapper()
        {
            CreateMap<vendorBasicDetailsbyChannelModel , VendorMode>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

**And add this dependency in the program class :**

```
builder.Service.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

And finally, it is enough to use the ***IMapper dependency*** in your ProtoBuff service